# Cluelessly searching for words

Tags: word-search

Below is a word search puzzle presented without clues. Instead, you must use the additional rules (see example below) to work out what the words are. Finally, as a check to make sure you found the right words, the first letters of each word can be rearranged to make one last, related word.

### Rules

- The words can run in any direction (orthogonal or diagonal) and do not have to be in straight lines
- Words do not overlap and their paths do not cross
- All letters are part of some word
- All words are of the same length
- All words (including the final word) are related somehow
- All words (including the final word) can be found in an English dictionary
- The letters that make up the final word do not appear in any specific location on the grid

### Example

Here's a short example.

[image: P O A W. E N N S. M U Y A. S T O D.]

[image: PONY EMUS TOAD SWAN]

The four words here are PONY, EMUS, TOAD and SWAN, which are all animals, and the first letter of each makes the word PETS.

### Puzzle

What is the final word to be found in this grid of letters?

[image: C E N A I U. L I R S R D. A M O G U R. E L N I O F. E C I T L E. T I S I V S.]

Comment: This is all in english, right?

Comment: Yes. All words that should be in an English dictionary.

Comment: Is it a coincidence that all letters in the grid are part of the words, or is that another rule?

Comment: It's not a coincidence. I suppose it should be a rule.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Words:

> FRUITS
> OLIVES
> OMELET
> DURIAN
> ICINGS
> ECLAIR

Final word:

> FOODIE

Here's a graphic:

> [image]

Comment: That was way too fast. :) Good job. (Maybe I should have gone for an 8x8 after all.) Any suggestions for improving this kind of puzzle?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor The only thing I'd say is pay attention to uncommon letters and where you put them. Sticking V so close to a corner really narrowed down the word possibilities and gave me a pretty good starting point ("live" was a very likely letter sequence, and that also meant that "lives" was just as likely, so "olives" was the first word I found).