# Cluelessly searching for words II

Tags: word-search

Below is a word search puzzle presented without clues. Instead, you must use the additional rules (see example below) to work out what the words are. Finally, as a check to make sure you found the right words, the first letters of each word can be rearranged to make one last, related word.

This is a second, harder puzzle. [See here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16087/cluelessly-searching-for-words) for the easier first puzzle.

### Rules

- The words can run in any direction (orthogonal or diagonal) and do not have to be in straight lines
- Words do not overlap and their paths do not cross
- All letters are part of some word
- All words are of the same length
- All words (including the final word) are related somehow
- All words (including the final word) have an English Wikipedia page, even if they are not English themselves
- The letters that make up the final word do not appear in any specific location on the grid

### Example

Here's a short example.

[image: P O A W. E N N S. M U Y A. S T O D.]

[image: PONY EMUS TOAD SWAN]

The four words here are PONY, EMUS, TOAD and SWAN, which are all animals, and the first letter of each makes the word PETS.

### Puzzle

What is the final word to be found in this grid of letters?

[image: M A N E A P N. D N A I K A A. A E O S U L A. N S O V U S S. I M O R H A U. L E O R T M R. M G R D A M E.]

### Hint

> All the words are taken from one set of Wikipedia list pages

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The full list of words is:

> [Domovoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domovoi)
>  [Rusalka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rusalka)
>  [Amemasu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amemasu)
>  [Gremlin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gremlin)
>  [Orthrus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthrus)
>  [Napaeae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napaeae)
>  [Sandman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandman)

As can be seen here:

> [image: word search]

With the final word being:

> [Dragons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon)

All words being:

> [Mythical/legendary creatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_legendary_creatures)

Comment: Ack, just a little too slow!

Comment: @Pete Hrm, you were slower but your answer is better... +1 to both of you!

Comment: @Pete - Don't you hate that... Though for what it's worth, I agree with Engineer Toast, so +1, and if OP wants to give you the tick that's fine by me... (I'll see you at the 8x8 clueless word search showdown!)

Comment: I have to go with the first correct answer, but +1 to both. (That said, I'm trusting the comments here since both say "answered 5 hours ago.")

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor If you hover over the "5 hours ago", you get the exact UTC time of each post, down to the second.

Answer (score 29):

The solution is:

> [image]

1

> [AMEMASU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amemasu) - A giant whale- or fish-like creature from Ainu folklore

2

> [DOMOVOI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domovoi) -  A protective house spirit in Slavic folklore

3

> [NAPAEAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napaeae) - From Greek mythology, a type of nymph that lived in wooded valleys, glens or grottoes

4

> [GREMLIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gremlin) - A fantastic creature commonly depicted as mischievous and mechanically oriented, with a specific interest in aircraft. (This is the first one I found, without this I would have been lost)

5

> [ORTHRUS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthrus) - A two-headed dog in Greek mythology

6

> [RUSALKA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rusalka) - A water nymph, a female spirit in Slavic mythology

7

> [SANDMAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandman) - A mythical character in central and northern European folklore who brings good dreams by sprinkling magical sand onto the eyes of people while they sleep at night

The final, related word is

> [DRAGONS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon) - Legendary creatures, typically with serpentine or reptilian traits, that feature in the myths of many cultures

They are all

> mythological creatures

All text quoted from the relevant Wikipedia articles.