# Clueslessly searching for words III

Tags: word-search

Below is a word search puzzle presented without clues. Instead, you must use the additional rules (see example below) to work out what the words are. Finally, as a check to make sure you found the right words, the first letters of each word can be rearranged to make one last, related word.

This is the third puzzle in a series. [Here's a 6x6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16087/cluelessly-searching-for-words), and [here's a 7x7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16094/cluelessly-searching-for-words-ii).

### Rules

- The words can run in any direction (orthogonal or diagonal) and do not have to be in straight lines
- Words do not overlap and their paths do not cross
- All letters are part of some word
- All words are of the same length
- All words (including the final word) are related somehow
- All words (including the final word) have an English Wikipedia page, even if they are not English themselves
- The letters that make up the final word do not appear in any specific location on the grid

### Example

Here's a short example.

[image: P O A W. E N N S. M U Y A. S T O D.]

[image: PONY EMUS TOAD SWAN]

The four words here are PONY, EMUS, TOAD and SWAN, which are all animals, and the first letter of each makes the word PETS.

### Puzzle

What is the final word to be found in this grid of letters?

[image: R E L A S T I E. E N N E H F P F. G A S R I F A H. G A S W E T T O. S E N A A H R C. W A Y E L E G S. L A I G D D I E. A B R T H R I N.]

### Hint

> All the words are taken from one set of Wikipedia list pages

Comment: Not _entirely_ clueless... BTW, is the list [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lists_of_lists)? :/

Comment: Well, yes, but that doesn't really narrow it down much. :) (The hint implies it's from a more specific list within that though.)

Comment: Ohh so it is a list, and any list that occurs on said list also may contain an entry?

Comment: Would I be on the right track if I found a US-centric proper noun?

Comment: That sounds likely.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution is:

> [image: SolvedPuzzle]

1

> [THIESSEN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiffani_Thiessen) - Tiffani (b. 1974), is an American actress

2

> [HATHAWAY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_Hathaway) - Anne (b. 1982), is an American actress, singer, and producer.

3

> [ELDRIDGE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florence_Eldridge) - Florence (1901 - 1988), was an American actress.

4

> [SALENGER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meredith_Salenger) - Meredith (b. 1970),  is an American actress.

5

> [PFEIFFER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelle_Pfeiffer) - Michelle (b. 1958),  is an American actress and singer.

6

> [INESCORT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frieda_Inescort) - Frieda (1901 - 1976), was a Scottish-born actress.

7

> [ALBRIGHT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lola_Albright) - Lola (b. 1924), is an American singer and actress

8

> [NAGASAWA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masami_Nagasawa) - Masami (b. 1987), is a Japanese actress.

The final, related word is

> THESPIAN

They are all

> [female movie actors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_female_movie_actors_by_name) (thespians)

All text quoted from the relevant Wikipedia articles.

Comment: That was most enjoyable, thank you! You had me looking for American politicians given I got #1 first. But once I realised the top right corner should be gettable given all the consonants, I found #6 and things started moving!

Comment: This is incredible! I wanna know how you managed this. The puzzle seemed completely impregnable, and having proper nouns as the words to be found makes it even harder.

Comment: Very good job. I'm not sure I'll be able to make one harder than this without resorting to really obscure words and connections.

Comment: +1 Well done! I had 7, 3 & 6 yesterday before I ran out of time. Interestingly I was on the US politicians path initially too because of Albright. :)

Comment: @rand al'thor *SPOILERS* So this is kind of how I solved it. Stare at it for ages. See BRIGHT, then ALBRIGHT. Assuming this is correct then we're looking for female US politicians, US politicians, politicians, women? All too vague. Find out albright is a type of knot. Look up a list of knots. Not many 8 letter knots. See the comments about proper nouns. Looks like I might be on the right track with politicians. Stare at it some more. See RIDGE - so ALDRIDGE, LEDRIDGE, ELDRIDGE? Haven't heard of such named politicians. Whatever, if one of those is correct that pretty much forces INESCORT (cont)

Comment: *SPOILERS*  Is that even a surname? Looks like there was an actress with it. Actresses then? Find a male actor called Albright. Actors of any gender then? Well, I need to go to bed and I can't see anything in the rest of the grid... Have a look at lunch - don't hold out much hope but then realise that the top right of the grid is all consonants that are difficult to string together. Try P and F together. Aha, PFEIFFER! Must be a list of actors (with gender or something else in common?). HATHAWAY follows quickly, as does THIESSEN (not many options for the T at this stage). (cont.)

Comment: *SPOILERS* Go back to ELDRIDGE and ALBRIGHT. Find actresses that match the names so female actors must be the connection. Last two are quick even though I haven't heard the names since there aren't many options left.

Comment: Well, I'm still really impressed, even though it makes more sense now :-)