# Cluelessly searching for words IV

Tags: word-search

Below is a word search puzzle presented without clues. Instead, you must use the additional rules (see example below) to work out what the words are. Finally, as a check to make sure you found the right words, the first letters of each word can be rearranged to make one last, related word.

Because I'm having fun making these, this is the fourth puzzle in a series. Here's the [first](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16087/cluelessly-searching-for-words), [second](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16094/cluelessly-searching-for-words-ii) and [third](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16122/clueslessly-searching-for-words-iii). (This ought to be somewhere between the second and third difficulty-wise.)

### Rules

- The words can run in any direction (orthogonal or diagonal) and do not have to be in straight lines
- Words do not overlap and their paths do not cross
- All letters are part of some word
- All words are of the same length
- All words (including the final word) are related somehow
- All words (including the final word) have an English Wikipedia page, even if they are not English themselves
- The letters that make up the final word do not appear in any specific location on the grid

### Example

Here's a short example.

[image: P O A W. E N N S. M U Y A. S T O D.]

[image: PONY EMUS TOAD SWAN]

The four words here are PONY, EMUS, TOAD and SWAN, which are all animals, and the first letter of each makes the word PETS.

### Puzzle

What is the final word to be found in this grid of letters?

[image: I N I M O A N. L G R G R M T. L M A O U I H. A F N B S R L. L D S A A N M. E I R I G D I. H D E A L U R.]

### Hint

> All the words are taken from one Wikipedia list page

Comment: I'd ask you to be careful that this might be classified as a mass-producible puzzle.

Comment: I hadn't seen anything against that. I have one more (very hard one) after this, and then I was going to stop anyway though.

Comment: That's alright, then. It's just that we don't want hundreds of puzzles of a specific structure ruining around the site polluting it. Imagine if somebody posted a Sudoku every day.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. There's also a diminishing return on reputation gain for "more of the same" (which I think I'm already running in to). In any case, I was going to wait until this one gets solved to post the last one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution:

> [image]

Words:

> **B**OROMIR
> **A**REDHEL
> **G**ANDALF
> **G**AMLING
>  **I**SILDUR
> **N**IMLOTH
> **S**ARUMAN

They are all

> [Middle Earth Characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Middle-earth_characters)

Comment: < applause >  :-)