# Cluelessly searching for words V (last one)

Tags: word-search

Below is a word search puzzle presented without clues. Instead, you must use the additional rules (see example below) to work out what the words are. Finally, as a check to make sure you found the right words, the first letters of each word can be rearranged to make one last, related word.

This is the fifth and final puzzle in a series. Here's the [first](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16087/cluelessly-searching-for-words), [second](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16094/cluelessly-searching-for-words-ii), [third](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16122/clueslessly-searching-for-words-iii) and [fourth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16171/cluelessly-searching-for-words-iv/). I'll be a bit surprised if this one is solvable without hints.

### Rules

- The words can run in any direction (orthogonal or diagonal) and do not have to be in straight lines
- Words do not overlap and their paths do not cross
- All letters are part of some word
- All words are of the same length
- All words (including the final word) are related somehow
- All words (including the final word) have an English Wikipedia page, even if they are not English themselves
- The letters that make up the final word do not appear in any specific location on the grid

### Example

Here's a short example.

[image: P O A W. E N N S. M U Y A. S T O D.]

[image: PONY EMUS TOAD SWAN]

The four words here are PONY, EMUS, TOAD and SWAN, which are all animals, and the first letter of each makes the word PETS.

### Puzzle

What is the final word to be found in this grid of letters?

[image: O R A H A D K W A L. T H L O R U Y T E A. M O S E K E L I T T. E I A A L E S A P O. R S H U T L K U N E. I U A R I P O V L A. L S U T A O T N A T. I O S R R R V O E T. S U N A I O E A S I. U C H A L T A N C R.]

### Hint

> All the words are taken from one Wikipedia list page

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This one took a lot of work! :)

The words are:

1.

> DAHALOKELY

2.

> ILOKELESIA

3.

> NEOVENATOR

4.

> ORTHOMERUS

5.

> SATURNALIA

6.

> ALETOPELTA

7.

> UTAHRAPTOR

8.

> RUKWATITAN

9.

> ILIOSUCHUS

10.

> ACRISTAVUS

They are all

> Different species of dinosaurs

Which gives the secret word:

> DINOSAURIA

Image:

> [image]

The words are from this wiki page:

> [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dinosaur_genera)

Full disclosure: I wrote a script to help me solve this

Comment: Dangit! I knew it was dinosaurs but I couldn't find them all...

Comment: That's pretty amazing. I have no idea how you even got started on that one. I was sure that I'd have to offer some hints on that one.

Comment: I didn't solve it by hand, that I think would have been pretty much impossible, it was monstrously difficult! I wrote a script to help find possible words. I'll update my answer to reflect this!

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. I wonder if it'd be doable by hand if you already knew the secret word? (Though, that might actually make it a bit too easy.)